# No Reverse signal in car harness. Connection comes from reverse light?

Tags: nissan, car, camera, backup-camera

So a while back i setup an aftermarket touchscreen radio that has reverse cam support but my ***car*** harness does not have a reverse signal wire and the new radio harness does, of course. Where does the reverse signal come from on the car? I think im overthinking it since im an IT and in the IT world, stuff like this is different. I have researched about it and some people are hooking it up to the reverse light. Is it as simple as that? i thought there was some box with wires in the car that had all these switches or whatever to do different things.

I just want to make sure this would work before i do anything.

Vehicle i have is a Nissan Versa 2014 Sedan

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transmission range switch is were the signal comes from. In your case the Intelligent Power Distribution Module sends power to the range switch. Then sends power to various circuits depending on switch position. On the Versa the reverse lights have a direct path to the switch so tapping into the reverse light circuit is the easiest (in the cab) and only way to supply your reverse signal.

Comment: awesome! thanks for the quick reply! i will start today :D